# Hiphop VM and running against a php file

Tags: hiphop

I'm having trouble running a php file against the hip hop virtual machine. I setup a new Ubuntu 12.04 server, installed according to [this guideline](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Prebuilt-packages-on-ubuntu-12.04), however when trying to following examples from the [Running HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/running-hiphop) page, it goes south.

Namely:

```
ubuntu:~$ $HPHP_HOME/src/hhvm/hhvm --hphp sample.php 
-bash: /src/hhvm/hhvm: No such file or directory
```

I'm kind of at a loss as I haven't found many examples of how to run it exactly.

Comment: `/src/hhvm/hhvm: No such file or directory` sounds like `$HPHP_HOME` is not defined. What does `echo $HPHP_HOME` return?

Comment: It gives me an empty string. Which is strange since I spun up a brand new instance and installed their package directly. `which hhvm` gives me `/usr/bin/hhvm`

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the package, check for `/usr/bin/hhvm` and use that to run your scripts. I added some more examples to https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Running-HipHop-VM

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is reasonable to follow up a one-year old question.

The Hello world example at

```
 https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Running-HipHop-VM
```

likely assumes some configuration, like PHP home, is already set before doing that. W/o config, curl cannot work and get hello.php.

To config, come up with config.hdf, following

```
 https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Runtime-options
```

then do

```
hphp/hhvm/hhvm -m server -c config.hdf
```